# Attempt to present <ViewController:> on <UITabBarController > whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios7, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I want a particular tab to be opened at launch time in a tab bar application.I get the warning`Warning: Attempt to present <settingsViewController: 0x16e49870> on <UITabBarController: 0x16d25440> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

I tried in DidFinishLaunching

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;


numpadviewcontroller = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
settingsviewcontroller = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

But getting the same warning.I am using storyboards

I tried the code in viewWillAppear,ViewDidLoad also of the first controller of tab bar but i get the same error.

Comment: How are you creating the tabBarController and why are you presenting a view? Can you show more of the code?

Comment: i solved it ,i wrote the code for presenting in ViewDidAppear.The reason i presented the view,was to display a login screen,where i want tab bar controller as root view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In both viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad the ViewController's view has not been loaded in the window hierarchy yet. I would try to add the code in viewDidAppear.